# How to store user id session from login page in php

Tags: php, session, authentication

i am creating login page where user will be redirected to his/her profile page. Profile page contains the articles of that user...

> I have problem in login page, actually i want to store user id in
>   session from login page.. as i am storing user_email in session and it
>   does successfuly.. but it gives error on user_id session (undefined
>   index)....

**addition**
i want to show articles of logged in user through user_id session...

Here is the code of login page..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $user_email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_email']);
    $user_password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_password']);

    $encrypt= md5($user_password);

    $check_login="select * from users where customer_email='$user_email'
    AND customer_pass='$user_password'";

    $run_login= mysqli_query($con, $check_login);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_login);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($run_login);
    $user_id=['customer_id'];

    if($num==1){
        $_SESSION['customer_email']="$user_email";
        $_SESSION['customer_id']="$user_id";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "This Username Doesnt Exists or Empty Login !";
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like `$user_id=['customer_id'];` should be `$user_id=$row['customer_id'];`

Comment: Please provide the entire error, but as the comment above me says, most likely the error lies with the `$user_id = ...` line

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

- Do not forget to put `session_start()`;

**Step 2:**

- Change `$user_id=['customer_id'];` to `$user_id=$row['customer_id'];`

Comment: bro session is started on the top of page... and how to store step 2 in session?

Comment: Well, you've done it with `$_SESSION['customer_id']="$user_id";` @NisarAhmedNaseer

Answer (score 0):

You must set $user_id only if there is a return from DB (otherwize you don't know this id)

```
if($num==1){
    $user_id=$row['customer_id'];
    // ....
}
```

Comment: bro how user_id will be stored in session?

Comment: To store in the session:
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;